# Check if UView is inside Self.View bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a view that contains a UIScrollView that is designed to scroll horizontally. (So the UIScrollView is wider than the Self.View width)

Inside the UIScrollView I have a dozen UILables that I let the user cycle through adding values programmatically, when the next UILable is programmatically selected, if it is out of bounds I change the UIScrollViews offset to make sure the UILabel appears just to the left of the right side of the view.

This is how I am currently checking the UILabel position and then adjusting the offset of the UILabel.

```
if (positionLabel.frame.origin.x > self.view.frame.size.width) 
{
    [axisContainerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(positionLabel.frame.origin.x+40 - self.view.frame.size.width, axisContainerScrollView.frame.origin.y) 
                                     animated:YES];
} 
else if (positionLabel.frame.origin.x > self.view.frame.size.width) 
{
    axisContainerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, axisContainerScrollView.frame.origin.y) 
                                    animated:YES];
}
```

So positionLabel origin brings back the value of its position inside the UIScrollView then I change the offset of the axisContainerScrollView. The only problem with this is that if I scroll the view across and select a UILabel whose offset is already inside the view if send the label back across to the right..

I would like to adjust this if statement so that if the UILabel is inside the bounds of self.view then I don't want to change the offset.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the coordinate space of **positionLabel.frame** to be the same as **self.view**, then you can use **CGRectContainsRect** function to make the comparison you're wanting to do.

something like -

```
// convert label frame
CGRect comparisonFrame = [axisContainerScrollView convertRect:positionLabel.frame toView:self.view];
// check if label is contained in self.view
BOOL isContainedInView = CGRectContainsRect(self.view.frame, comparisonFrame);
```

Now you have a **BOOL**, you can place in any conditional, that you can use to check.

Comment: You may want to compare against self.view.bounds rather than self.view.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `[UIScrollView scrollRectToVisible:animated:]`? It may be a more elegant method to do what you want. I'm pretty sure it won't try to scroll if the rectangle is already visible.

Comment: Okay I will look into that now. I still dont feel this is going to fix my issue regarding not scrolling when the UILabel is inside the bounds already.